# Restructring the textfile based on pattern in the file

Tags: scala

I  would like to reformat the content of the text file using Scala such as for the given sample file:

```
"good service"
Tom Martin (USA) 17th October 2015    
4    
Hi my name is
Tom.
I love boardgames.
Aircraft    TXT-102   

"not bad"
M Muller (Canada) 22nd September 2015
6
Hi
I
like
boardgames.
Aircraft    TXT-101
Type Of Customer    Couple Leisure
Cabin Flown FirstClass
Route   IND to CHI
Date Flown  September 2015
Seat Comfort    12345
Cabin Staff Service 12345

.
.
```

Gets reformated to this:

```
"good service"
Tom Martin (USA) 17th October 2015    
4    
Hi my name is Tom. I love boardgames.
Aircraft    TXT-102    

"not bad"
M Muller (Canada) 22nd September 2015
6
Hi I like boardgames.
Aircraft    TXT-101
Type Of Customer    Couple Leisure
Cabin Flown FirstClass
Route   IND to CHI
Date Flown  September 2015
Seat Comfort    12345
Cabin Staff Service 12345

.
.
```

I have identified the pattern of my file, which is: This multi-line string comes between a digit and word separated by tabs. 
For example, first block's multi line content comes between `4 and Aircraft    TXT-102`. Second block's multi line content comes between `6 and Aircraft    TXT-101` Also, blocks are delimited by two new lines.

I know of Pattern matching using regex can help but I do not know how to handle this on file.

Comment: If you have _any_ code that tries to handle this, please post it. It helps.

Answer (score 1):

What I'd do, in pseudocode:

```
while more lines available { 
    lines_so_far = read input until a number is seen
    output(lines_so_far)
    lines_to_join = read input until "Aircraft" is seen
    output(joined lines_to_join)
}
```

A regexp for a line consisting of only a number is `^\d+$`; for a line starting with "Airline", `^Airline .*`. The convenience method to look at is [`takeWhile`](http://allaboutscala.com/tutorials/chapter-8-beginner-tutorial-using-scala-collection-functions/scala-takewhile-example/).